# Store cout from function as string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a function that takes in a vector of integers and outputs them via `std::cout`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void final_sol(std::vector<int> list){
    for (int i ; i < list.size() ; i++){
        std::cout << list[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    final_sol(list);
    return 0;
}
```

However, from this point I would like to have a way to quickly obtain the outputs of `final_sol(vector)` as a string. One way to do this would be to modify the original function to also create the string. However, I am not interested in modifying `final_sol(vector)`. Is there another way I could store the outputs as a string?

Comment: No. Not without modifying the contents of the function.

Comment: You don't want to modify the function, but you want to modify the function so you can have the string.  You can't have both of those at once.

Comment: IMO this down votes are a bit to harsh. Yes question is not perfect, but there are many much worse.

Comment: @WaterDrop On a side note: the `final_sol()` you have shown has *undefined behavior*, because `i` is uninitialized when `i < list.size()` is evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide overload:

```
void final_sol(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<int>& list){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++){
        out << list[i] << " ";
    }
}

void final_sol(const std::vector<int>& list){
    final_sol(std::cout, list);
}
```

This way you existing calling code will not be impacted - most probably this is what you want: not modifying function signature. Not what you described: not do not modifying implementation of final_sol.

Then you can do:

```cpp
std::ostringstream str;
final_sol(str, list);
auto s = str.str()
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are "*not interested in modifying `final_sol(vector)`*", that means you are stuck with `final_sol()` writing to `std::cout`, in which case you would have to change where `std::cout` outputs its data to.  You can use its [`rdbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) method for that purpose, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

void final_sol(const std::vector<int> &list){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << list[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // save pointer to std::cout buffer
    auto cout_buff = std::cout.rdbuf();
 
    // substitute std::cout buffer with 'local' buffer
    std::ostringstream local;
    std::cout.rdbuf(local.rdbuf());
 
    // now std::cout works with the 'local' buffer
    // so you won't see any console output here
    final_sol(list);
 
    // go back to the old buffer
    std::cout.rdbuf(cout_buff);
  
    // use the local buffer as needed ...
    std::cout << local.str();

    return 0;
}
```

However, a better way to approach this would be to either:

1. have `final_sol()` return a `std::string`, and then let the caller decide what to do with it, eg:

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <string>

   std::string final_sol(const std::vector<int> &list){
       std::string s;
       for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i){
           s += (std::to_string(list[i]) + " ");
       }
       return s;
   }

   int main(){
       std::vector<int> list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

       std::string s = final_sol(list);

       // use s as needed...
       std::cout << s;

       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. have `final_sol()` take a `std::ostream&` parameter, then let the caller decide where to write the output to, eg:

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #include <sstring>
   #include <vector>

   void final_sol(const std::vector<int> &list, std::ostream &out){
       for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i){
           out << list[i] << " ";
       }
   }

   int main(){
       std::vector<int> list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

       std::ostringstream oss;
       final_sol(list, oss);

       // use oss.str() as needed...
       std::cout << oss.str();

       return 0;
   }
   ```